# google-cloud/storage bucketFile.getSignedUrl connection error

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

So I´m having a similar problem as [this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLMoP.png). I´m getting a remote file url  uploading to a bucket inside a firebase function.

However this problem only happens for pdf type files.

For other types, that I´ve tested, like ms-word, ms-excel, ppt-presentation the upload happens and the public url is successfully returned.

## function index.js

```
  const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage'),
  fs = require('fs'), os = require('os'), path = require('path'),

  storage = new Storage({
  projectId: firebaseCredentials.projectId,
  keyFilename: './xxxv-xx.json'
  }),
  bucket = storage.bucket(firebaseCredentials.storageBucket),
  request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null })

  console.log(`bucket? -> \n ${bucket}`)

  return request.get(incomingMessageData.url, async (error, response, body) => {

  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), incomingMessageData.file)

  console.log(`tempFilePath -> ${tempFilePath} \n os.tmpdir() -> ${os.tmpdir()}`)

  fs.writeFile(tempFilePath, body, async err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`The file has been saved to temp storage! \n 
  Now starting to upload -> ${incomingMessageData.phone}/${incomingMessageData.file}
  `);


  try {

  console.log('inside try catch bucket upload')

      // this approach works
      const bucketFile = bucket.file(`${incomingMessageData.phone}/${incomingMessageData.file}`);
      await bucketFile.save(body)

      console.log('bucket upload finished')

      // the problem is happenning here. It´s throwing generic 'connection error' message that withouth further details is elusive to solve

      let result = await bucketFile.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'read',
        expires: '03-17-2025'
      }), url

      if (result[0].indexOf('http') < 0) {
        console.error('Error getting SignedUrl ', result);
        url = result.toString()
      } else {
        url = result[0]
      }


         let metadata = await bucketFile.getMetadata(),
         size = bytesToSize(metadata[0].size)

         // handle url 
         console.log(`${tempFilePath} uploaded to ${bucket.name}. \n Got 
           uploadUrl? -> ${url}`)
```

For pdf type files the gcp log is like this

[image]

And for other types of files, like ms-word, the log shows

[image]

Comment: Is this happening only for one specific PDF file, or for all? How big is the file?

Answer (score 0):

GC doesnt know you are creating a pdf so you have to create the file as a PDF. Its been answered here: [Create PDF in Firebase Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335543/create-pdf-in-firebase-cloud-functions/47477774)