# Firebase Storage and PDFkit. How specify MIME type?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, pdfkit

I am trying to create a PDF file using **Firebase Functions** and save it to **Firebase Storage.**
I used the code I found in this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335543/create-pdf-in-firebase-cloud-functions).

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const pdfkit = require('pdfkit');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createPDF = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const myPdfFile = admin.storage().bucket("gs://MYBUCKETNAME.appspot.com/").file('test.pdf');
    const doc = new pdfkit();
    const stream = doc.pipe(myPdfFile.createWriteStream());
    doc.fontSize(25).text('Hello World!', 100, 100);
    doc.end();

    stream.on('finish', function () {
        res.status(200).send({status: "ok"});
    });
});
```

**The problem:**

The code is working and the file is generated.
The problem is that the file is of MIME type *application/octet-stream*. So I can't download it or open it.
[image]

How can I save the pdf file and specify the MIME type? Or change it after creation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is necessary to define the metadata of the content type  for your file "contentType: 'application/pdf'"

For example:

```
const stream = doc.pipe(myPdfFile.createWriteStream( 
{metadata: { contentType: 'application/pdf'}));
```